# Semaphores : enhanced swimming pool

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

I am working on process synchronization, with an improved version of the swimming pool problem:

> Bathers want to go to the swimming pool:
>
> - They have to take an empty basket
> - They have to go in a free cubicle
> - They put their swimsuit on, put their clothes in the basket and leave the cubicle
> - They swim
> - They head back to a free cubicle with their basket
> - They put their clothes back on, and leave the cubicle
> - They give the empty basket back
> - There is a limited number of baskets and cubicles
> - If a bather can't find an empty basket or a free cubicle, he will wait until one is available
>
> ## IMPROVED VERSION:
>
> - There are members and non-members
> - The members have priority over non-members
> - If one resource becomes available, it will be given to a waiting member, and if there's not, it will be given to anyone waiting.

To do this, I thought I'd use 3 semaphores: one for the baskets, one for the cubicles, and one for the waiting members. This way, when a member is waiting, the semaphore would block any process calling `P(s_members)`, and when a member finally gets a basket, he calls `V(s_members)`. But there can be several members waiting in the queue, and the semaphore should not 'release' a non-member each time `V(s_members)` is called. That's why I thought `sembuf.sem_op = 0;` would be a good deal, because non-members would have to wait for 0.
The problem is that with this solution:

- non-members have to call `P(s_members)` before calling `P(s_basket)` or `P(s_cubicle)`.
- non-members have to call `P(s_members)` in order to fall asleep and be queued with others, but they need not to increase/decrease the value of the semaphore, because it doesn't depend on them.
- members waiting for resources need to call `P(s_members)` in order to increase/decrease its value (because they are in the queue), but they need not to fall asleep and continue waiting for their basket.
- imagine this case: a non-member is waiting for his basket, and there are no members in the queue at the moment. Then, a member shows up, and obviously, he is waiting for resources too. At this point, the non-members who were waiting too should fall asleep until the member leaves the queue, but they are already asleep waiting for their basket, which means they already called `P(s_members)`. As a result, the priority rule does not apply.

How can we solve that ?
I hope it's clear enough, it's hard to explain and easy to mess it up all.
Thank you for your time reading this.

**EDIT:**
Sorry if I posted this on the wrong StackExchange community, I will think twice about it next time!

Comment: It is not the job of stackoverflow to design your code, it is not the job of stackoverflow to perform the analysis of your problem scenario.  We are here to answer two kinds of questions  1) why does it not compile and 2) why is the wrong output being produced.   In either case, you must post your code, and in the first case indicate exactly what is not compiling.  and in the second case post the input, the expected output, and the actual output.   In general, no code, no help.  We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> imagine this case: a non-member is waiting for his basket, and there
>   are no members in the queue at the moment. Then, a member shows up,
>   and obviously, he is waiting for resources too. At this point, the
>   non-members who were waiting too should fall asleep until the member
>   leaves the queue, but they are already asleep waiting for their
>   basket, which means they already called P(s_members). As a result, the
>   priority rule does not apply.

So what you're saying is "if a non-member goes to sleep in the same queue as members do, we're screwed". I agree. Once a non-member goes to sleep in the queue, you can't exactly yank them out later.

Since non-members and members cannot wait for a resource on the same semaphore, `s_basket` must be wrong.

How about trying `s_basket_members` and `s_basket_nonmembers`?

I believe you will also need to keep track of a few `int`s as well, like how many members/non-members are waiting, and how many baskets are available.

Comment: I'm gonna try that out, I have a few ideas, thanks for the hint :-)